# mysql 8.0.30 installation on Windows Server 2022 very slow, what's wrong?

Tags: mysql

We are moving from a VM running Window 2012 and MySQL 5.7 with 8G of ram and one processor.

We are testing a mySQL 8.0.30 on a new Windows Server 2022 VM installation. It is a VM with 8G of ram , one processor. Pretty much the same setup.

Database is Innodb.

The 5.7 database was backed up with mysqldump and loaded into the new v8 server. I'm using the same my.ini in V8, with paths changed to point to the v8.0 data folder.

One rather complicated stored procedure runs great in 5.7. In v8 it crawls.
One step, processing 500 records at a time out of 115711 records, completes in 1 second or less in 5.7. In v8 it takes several minutes. I have calculated the total runtime would be appox. 200 hours.

After painful testing in a debugger, "queries" on a particualar table table take longer than expected.

```
select  postDate
    from  rej_pay
    where  claimno = 'xxxxx-xx-xxx'
      and  serv_seq = '0'
      and  `status` = ' '
      and  postdate is null;
```

and

```
update rej_pay set
        postdate = Current_date()
    where claimno = 'xxxxx-xx-xx'
      and serv_seq = '0'
      and `status` = ' ';
```

Table structure (I know some of the indexes are not needed):

```
CREATE TABLE `rej_pay` (
  `claimno` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `serv_seq` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `status` varchar(8) DEFAULT '',
  `level` varchar(8) DEFAULT '',
  `code` varchar(8) DEFAULT '',
  `desc` text,
  `trandate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `postdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `checknum` varchar(16) DEFAULT '',
  `release` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idxStatus` (`claimno`,`status`),
  KEY `idxPostDate` (`postdate`),
  KEY `idxCC` (`claimno`,`serv_seq`,`code`,`release`),
  KEY `idxClaimNo` (`claimno`),
  KEY `idxPosting` (`claimno`,`serv_seq`,`status`,`postdate`),
  KEY `idxCheckBuild` (`claimno`,`code`,`status`),
  KEY `idxStatus2` (`status`),
  KEY `idxCode` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1888168 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

The target table has approximately 3 million records and is compound indexed on the columns in the "where" clauses. I see a 3-5 second delay executing these statements in my debugger. However, executing them in Workbench is like 0.015 seconds. these are the only ones that are sluggish in the debugger.

I'm assuming (hoping) the issue is just with the ini settings.

my.ini below

```
[client]
port=3360

[mysql]
no-beep

[mysqld]
port=3360
datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0\Data
log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;
authentication_policy=mysql_native_password,,
default-storage-engine=INNODB
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
log-output=FILE
general-log=0
general_log_file="MARK-PC.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="MARK-PC-slow.log"
long_query_time=10
log-error="MARK-PC.err"
log-bin="MARK-PC-bin"
server-id=1
lower_case_table_names=1
secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads"
max_connections=151
table_open_cache=4000
tmp_table_size=17M
thread_cache_size=10
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=25M
key_buffer_size=8M
read_buffer_size=51K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_log_buffer_size=16M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=128M
innodb_log_file_size=48M
innodb_thread_concurrency=9
innodb_autoextend_increment=64
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_checksum_algorithm=0
back_log=80
flush_time=0
join_buffer_size=256K
max_allowed_packet=64M
max_connect_errors=100
open_files_limit=8161
sort_buffer_size=256K
table_definition_cache=2000
binlog_row_event_max_size=8K
sync_source_info=10000
sync_relay_log=10000
sync_relay_log_info=10000
loose_mysqlx_port=3361
```

Comment: Let's see a "slow" query.  And provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for that query.

Comment: @RickJames The offending query/insert has been elusive so far so I don't know exactly what to give you. My main focus at this point is why with the same data same stored procedures, same machine it would go from quite fast in 5.7 and extremely slow in 8.0. The database and stored procs are identical. Only thing that has varied is OS and MySQL Version. Do the above my.ini settings seem reasonable for v8?

Comment: There were numerous "improvements" with 8.0.  A small number of them actually slow down certain queries.  However, there is no definitive list of such.  By looking at a specific query, I can research the aspects of it that might have caused a slowdown.  Or I might see a way to speed it up irrespective of rhe version it is running on.  Use the slowlog:  [_SlowLog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog)

Comment: @RickJames After painful testing in a debugger, "queries" on a single table take longer than expected. select postDate from rej_pay where claimno = 'addis-11-053' and serv_seq = '0' and `status` = ' ' and postdate is null;
update rej_pay set postdate = Current_date() where claimno = 'addis-11-053' and serv_seq = '0' and `status` = ' ';

Comment: @RickJames I update my original question with the specific "queries".

Comment: Try to upgrade to 8.0.31. Also did you have a look at [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html)?

Comment: @RickJames Now that this has been moved to Database Administrators and unlocked I have edited the question again to add table structure

Comment: Drop index idxClaimNo from reg_pay.  It is redundant and may be getting in the way fo picking a better index.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `EXPLAIN UPDATE ...`

Comment: How many rows are involved in those queries?  (The slowlog should say.)

Comment: "One step, processing 500 records at a time" -- Is that in a loop?  Or a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this figured out.

The database I am using was loaded from a `mysqldump` backup from the live server's MySql.

When dumped some tables were `utf8` encoded others were `utf8mb3`.

New server is `uft8mb4` default coding.

Since the dump explicitly specified the encoding, MySql used what was provided.

I changed all the tables to `utf8mb4` and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=128M
```

Change to

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=5G
```

Comment: I really appreciate your going out of you way to help. See my answer for the resolution. I will look into the indexing and I had already change the innodb_buffer_pool_size to 5G